# Why is Spring cloud data flow tutorial not showing expected result

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to complete the first spring cloud dataflow tutorial and I'm not getting the result in the tutorial.

https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/

The tutorial has me use curl to a http source and see the result in the log sink with a tail of a file of stdout.

I do not see the result. I see the startup in the log.

I tail the log
docker exec -it skipper tail -f /path/from/stdout/textbox/in/dashboard

I enter
curl http://localhost:20100 -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "Happy streaming"

all I see is

```
2020-10-05 16:30:03.315  INFO 110 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 2.0.1
2020-10-05 16:30:03.316  INFO 110 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2020-10-05 16:30:03.322  INFO 110 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-10-05 16:30:03.338  INFO 110 --- [           main] s.i.k.i.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter@106faf11
2020-10-05 16:30:03.364  INFO 110 --- [container-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : Cluster ID: 2J0QTxzQQmm2bLxFKgRwmA
2020-10-05 16:30:03.574  INFO 110 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 20041 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-05 16:30:03.584  INFO 110 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.a.l.s.k.LogSinkKafkaApplication  : Started LogSinkKafkaApplication in 38.086 seconds (JVM running for 40.251)
2020-10-05 16:30:05.852  INFO 110 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=http-ingest] Discovered group coordinator kafka-broker:9092 (id: 2147482646 rack: null)
2020-10-05 16:30:05.857  INFO 110 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=http-ingest] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2020-10-05 16:30:05.858  INFO 110 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1  : partitions revoked: []
2020-10-05 16:30:05.858  INFO 110 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=http-ingest] (Re-)joining group
2020-10-05 16:30:08.943  INFO 110 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=http-ingest] Successfully joined group with generation 1
2020-10-05 16:30:08.945  INFO 110 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=http-ingest] Setting newly assigned partitions [http-ingest.http-0]
2020-10-05 16:30:08.964  INFO 110 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=http-ingest] Resetting offset for partition http-ingest.http-0 to offset 0.
2020-10-05 16:30:08.981  INFO 110 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1  : partitions assigned: [http-ingest.http-0]
```

No Happy streaming

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for trying out the developer guides!

From what I can tell, it appears the `http | log` stream definition in SCDF is submitted without an explicit port. When that is the case, a port gets randomly assigned by Spring Boot when the `http-source` and `log-sink` applications start.

If you navigate to your `http-source` application logs, you will see the application port listed, and that is the port you'd use on the CURL command.

There's this following note about this in the guide for your reference.

> If you use the local Data Flow Server, add the following deployment property to set the port to avoid a port collision.

Alternatively, you can deploy the stream with an explicit port in the definition. For example: `http --server.port=9004 | log`. With that, your CURL would then be:

> curl http://localhost:9004 -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "Happy streaming"